# Java Custom Properties in environment.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration

I have an application that hooks up to an FTP site to scrape data from files posted by a third party. We also have an in-house sandbox ftp site for testing.

I am looking to make the FTP information configurable such that the application may target the sandbox in the development and staging environments while the production environment can target the third party vendor's FTP site. I would like to do this through config files. How would I target a specified config file or configuration based on the environment I'm in.

I assume I'll need to do something in the environment.xml but I am relatively new to Java so I am looking for some insight on best practices.

The contents of the file would be ftp server, username, and password and can vary based on environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a different properties file for each region. See this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) for a tutorial.